# How to setup a mail server on Ubuntu to send and receive mail?

Tags: email, postfix, mail, mail-server

For the last couple of days I have been trying to setup my VPS server to send and receive emails without using 3rd party services (e.g. gmail, hotmail...).

I have a website hosted on my VPS that is using LAMP (Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 7.1)
I installed Postfix and was successfully able to send emails using PHP, however what I want is to be able to read and reply to emails that users send to my website email (e.g. contact@example.com) so I googled on how to do this and most of the answers I was able to find was used some external SMTP like gmail.

My DNS Records look something like this with the exception of using the **proper server IP and proper domain name**:

```
|Type | Name                | Value                                    | TTL        |
|-----|---------------------|------------------------------------------|------------|
|A    | @                   | 127.0.0.1                                | 600 seconds|
|CNAME| *                   | @                                        | 600 seconds|
|CNAME| email               | email.example.com                        | 1 Hour     |
|CNAME| ftp                 | @                                        | 1 Hour     |
|CNAME| www                 | @                                        | 1 Hour     |
|MX   | @                   | mail.example.com (Priority: 10)          | 1 Hour     |
|SRV  | _autodiscover._tcp.@| 0 0 443 autodiscover.int.secureserver.net| 1 Hour     |
|NS   | @                   | ns45.domaincontrol.com                   | 1 Hour     |
|NS   | @                   | ns46.domaincontrol.com                   | 1 Hour     |
```

I don't want to use gmail, I want to host and to be able to send and receive email from my own server, and maybe connect contact@example.com to thunderbird or outlook.

Note that my problem is not if I did setup my server correctly but how to setup my server correctly to accomplish sending and receiving emails without relying  on services supplied by gmail and others like it.

Comment: Do you have any registered domain for your emails?

Comment: yes I do have a registered domain

Comment: Do you also have an MX record for your registered domain? If not you will not be able to receive emails.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy yes I do, I did set it up to direct to mo server.